# Protractor - run test again if fails

Tags: shell, protractor, angularjs-e2e, false-positive

I'm using shell script to run protractor tests.
I want to make sure that if the test fails (exit code != 0) then it will run again - three times most.
I'm already using Teamcity, but Teamcity sends the 'FAIL' email and only then tries again. I want the test will run three times before sending a message.
this is part of my script:

```
if [ "$#" -eq 0 ];
then
/usr/local/bin/protractor proactor-config.js --suite=sanity
```

now I want to somehow check whether the Exit Code was 0  and of not - run again.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a small module to do this called [protractor flake](https://github.com/NickTomlin/protractor-flake/). It can be used via the cli

```
# defaults to 3 attempts
protractor-flake -- protractor.conf.js
```

Or [programatically](https://github.com/NickTomlin/protractor-flake#usage).

One nice thing here is that it will only re-run *failed* spec files, instead of your test suite.

There is a long standing [feature request](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1190) for this in the protractor issue queue. It probably won't be baked into the core of the framework.

Comment: thanks, I will try it and let you know how it worked.

Answer (score 1):

function to check status

```
function test {
    "$@"
    local status=$?
    if [ $status -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "error with $1" >&2
    fi
    return $status
}

test command1
test command2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `protractor` with `cucumber-js`, you can choose to give each scenario (or all scenarios tagged as unstable) a number of retries:

```
./node_modules/cucumber/bin/cucumber-js --help
...
  --retry <NUMBER_OF_RETRIES>     specify the number of times to retry failing test cases (default: 0) (default: 0)
  --retryTagFilter <EXPRESSION>   only retries the features or scenarios with tags matching the expression (repeatable).
          This option requires '--retry' to be specified. (default: "")
```

Unfortunately if every failed scenario has been successfully retried, Protractor will still return with exit code 1:
https://github.com/protractor-cucumber-framework/protractor-cucumber-framework/issues/176

As a workaround, when starting the `protractor` I append the following to its command line:

```js
const directory = 'build';
ensureDirSync(directory);
const cucumberSummary = join(directory, 'cucumberSummary.log');

protractorCommandLine += ` --cucumberOpts.format=summary:${cucumberSummary} \
      || grep -P "^(\\d*) scenarios? \\(.*?\\1 passed" ${cucumberSummary} \
      && rm ${cucumberSummary}`;
```